# Challenging other players using Facebook API with the same data

Tags: android, json, facebook

I'm in course of developing an application, which basically is a quiz. I store all the questions on an external server, and fetch them as JSON files. I'd like to implement some Facebook features, most importantly the possibility of challenging other players. However, in order to compare the results, I'd like that other user to use the same set of questions in a current game, as I do - situation similar as in SongPop, where two players guess the same songs. I'm not sure though if it's possible for a standard Android app, not Facebook app like SongPop. I'm looking for a way of somehow sending a 'data pack' to him, containing the questions I have for the current challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Question Set which is a collection of Questions.

e.g. QuestionSet1 will contain Question2, Question4, Question5.

You can just send QuestionSet1 to the user being challenged. e.g. mysite.com/game/?questionsetid=1

On your server, if the url contains the parameter 'questionsetid', that meets you'll get the questions from the Question Set.

Comment: Okay, so it is possible. However, could you give me a hand, how do I do this? How exactly can I send this collection of questions to the recipient? Which functions to implement?

Comment: You have to build that on your server. Create a database that stores the questions and question sets.

Comment: Okay, but I wanted to do it like this: for each new game I begin, I randomize the questions (pick them randomly from the database), so the question set is defined only after I started the game. And I wonder, how do I pass it after that? I don't have ready, predefined question sets.

Comment: For every new game, you create a new Question Set on your server. You select a random Question and you can that Question to the new Question Set. When the user is done playing that game, you can send the Question Set to the player being challenged.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it, but I'm not sure how, I mean, is it possible via FB? Cuz I have to know, to which user I'm sending it. Sorry for so many questions, I'm really new to that stuff.

Comment: Yes it's possible. You need to add Facebook Login for your app. Once the user authorized your app, you can get access to the friend list & you can send requests.